# Why is the Croatian word "vjetar" spelt with "je" rather than "e"?

Tags: bosnian-croatian-serbian

Why is the Croatian word "vjetar" spelt with "je" rather than "e"? "je" comes from Proto-Slavic yat, and 'e' comes from Proto-Slavic 'en'. But there was 'en' in Proto-Slavic word for "wind", as we see by Latin "ventus" and English "wind".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Proto-Slavic original word for ‘wind’ [did have](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/v%C4%9Btr%D1%8A) the *yat’* (ě):

> *vě̀trъ *m* — From Proto-Balto-Slavic **wētras*, from Proto-Indo-European **h₂weh₁-*. Cognate with Lithuanian *vė́tra* (“storm”), Latvian *vētra* (“storm”), Old Prussian *wetro* (“wind”), Latin *ventus* (“wind”), Sanskrit *वाति* (vāti, “to blow”).

Latin *ventus* [is derived](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ventus#Etymology_1) from the same PIE root *h₂weh₁-* with the participial suffix *-nt-*:

> ventus *m* — From Proto-Italic *wentos, from Proto-Indo-European **h₂wéh₁n̥ts* (“blowing”), present participle of **h₂weh₁-* (“to blow”).

Answer (score 4):

The vjetar comes from proto-Slavic [větrъ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/v%C4%9Btr%D1%8A), from Proto-Balto-Slavic [wētras](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/v%C4%9Btr%D1%8A), from PIE ***h₂weh₁tros***, so there was no "-en-" in it.

The Latin "ventus" and English "wind" [come](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%82w%C3%A9h%E2%82%81n%CC%A5ts) from PIE ***h₂wéh₁n̥ts***.